# Bracket typeclass in cats-effect 0.10.1

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, io-monad

I'm using cats-effect 0.10.1 and found out that there is no `Bracket` typeclass in this version. So this seems I need to introduce some workaround for that.

I'm designing function for Reading from some source (side-effect). So I have \

```
trait DataFormat

object StreamData{

  def apply[T](path: String)(f: (DataFormat, ReadableByteChannel) => T): IO[T] = 
  IO {
     val channel: ReadableByteChannel = Files.newByteChannel(path)
     try{
        val dataFormat: DataFormat = //...
        //in case of GZIP format open GZIPInputStream
        f(dataFormat, channel)
     } finally {
        if(channel != null) channel.close()
     }
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that `f: (DataFormat, ReadableByteChannel) => T` is impure. So I'd make it as `f: (DataFormat, ReadableByteChannel) => IO[T]` which makes resource releasing in the example above not possible (because I need to `flatMap` in this case).

Can you suggest any workarounds about it and yet keeping functions pure?

Comment: I assume upgrading to 1.0.0-RC isn't a possibility?

Comment: BTW, which resource needs releasing, `T`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Unfortunately, no. I also cannot switch to `scalaz-effect` which also includes that.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have some function that depending on the data-format and channel creates `fs2.Stream[IO, Array[Byte]]` and does some processing. But after that I want to release the channel, that's it.

Comment: How about creating a thin typeclass for resource releasing? Do you need any other properties for the effect around `T`? Do you need to `map`, `flatMap` etc?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov You mean similar to `Bracket` of `1.0.0-RC`? Only `map`, but this look straightworward to implement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172690/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-some-name).